# For loop to remove non-strings from a list

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to iterate over the list elemets and remove non-string items. However the loop is failing and removing strings as well.

```
currency.unique()
```

array(['CADCAD', 'CADCHF', 'CADEUR', 'CADGBp', 'CADUSD', 'CADNOK', nan,
'CADMXN'], dtype=object)

```
Forex_ticker=list(currency.unique())

for item in Forex_ticker:
    if type(item)!='str':
        print(item,type(item),Forex_ticker)
        Forex_ticker.remove(item)
    else:
        continue
```

CADCAD <class 'str'> ['CADCAD', 'CADCHF', 'CADEUR', 'CADGBp', 'CADUSD', 'CADNOK', nan, 'CADMXN']
CADEUR <class 'str'> ['CADCHF', 'CADEUR', 'CADGBp', 'CADUSD', 'CADNOK', nan, 'CADMXN']
CADUSD <class 'str'> ['CADCHF', 'CADGBp', 'CADUSD', 'CADNOK', nan, 'CADMXN']
nan <class 'float'> ['CADCHF', 'CADGBp', 'CADNOK', nan, 'CADMXN']

```
Forex_ticker
```

```
['CADCHF', 'CADGBp', 'CADNOK', 'CADMXN']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing from the list while iterating, which is always a bad idea. To remove the `nan` values from the array, you can use `pandas.isnull` function:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(
    [
        "CADCAD",
        "CADCHF",
        "CADEUR",
        "CADGBp",
        "CADUSD",
        "CADNOK",
        np.nan,
        "CADMXN",
    ],
    dtype=object,
)

a = a[~pd.isnull(a)]
print(a)
```

Prints:

```
['CADCAD' 'CADCHF' 'CADEUR' 'CADGBp' 'CADUSD' 'CADNOK' 'CADMXN']
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had never seen this "a = a[~pd.isnull(a)]" before -- very useful.